# how many LiveData do I need to have in my repositoy if I get data from 3 different rest API?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

say for example I have restaurant object. I have 3 different activities

1. one activity to show list of top recommended restaurants
2. one activity to show list of search result restaurants
3. one activity to show list of visited restaurants

so I have 3 different endpoint from backend that I will fetch using retroft. those 3 endpoints will give me restaurants data, same POJO

so for those 3 activities, I need to make 3 different viewmodels, and I will have 1 repository right ? my question is, how many LiveData do I have to make to send data to my activity ?

3 liveData in one repository like this

```
class VideoRepository {

    val recommendedRestaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...
    val searchResultsRestaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...
    val visitedRestaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...

    fun getRecommendedRestaurant() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRecommendedRestaurant()
    }

    fun getRestaurantsUsingFilter() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRestaurantsUsingFilter()
    }

    fun getVisitedRestaurants() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getVisitedRestaurants
    }

}
```

or just 1 LiveData in my repository ? so every search result will be sent back to activities through only one LiveData like this

```
class VideoRepository {

        val restaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...

        fun getRecommendedRestaurant() {
            RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRecommendedRestaurant()
        }

        fun getRestaurantsUsingFilter() {
            RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRestaurantsUsingFilter()
        }

        fun getVisitedRestaurants() {
            RestaurantRetrofitClient.getVisitedRestaurants
        }

    }
```

Comment: it's depend on your business, I means both of them it not a programming problem

Comment: @GianhTran could you please give an example sir ? I don't understand if I need to use 3 or just one livedata

Answer (score 1):

The better solution can be u can create three repo for three screens and split the API calls.

Because u have to create three repo instance for all the viewmodel for the three screens. This will increase the memory.

If you are using a sharedViewModel concept means then you can go for Option A in your code. Because sharedViewModel will have only one instance, for three screens.

```
class VideoRepository {

    val recommendedRestaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...
    val searchResultsRestaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...    
    val visitedRestaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...

    fun getRecommendedRestaurant() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRecommendedRestaurant()
    }

    fun getRestaurantsUsingFilter() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRestaurantsUsingFilter()
    }

    fun getVisitedRestaurants() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getVisitedRestaurants
    }

}
```

If you are well enough to handle the data using liveData you can go for Option B

```
 class VideoRepository {

    val restaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = ...

    fun getRecommendedRestaurant() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRecommendedRestaurant()
    }

    fun getRestaurantsUsingFilter() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getRestaurantsUsingFilter()
    }

    fun getVisitedRestaurants() {
        RestaurantRetrofitClient.getVisitedRestaurants
    }

}
```

Comment: so the most common way is by making a repository for each viewmodel I have inmy Android app ? sorry I am new in MVVM in Android.

Comment: This will be preferable a good way to do so... If you are having a common place to get data means, it wont be considered as MVVM, it will be considering as MVP architecture

Comment: I think same viewmodel is enough for these three things. I prefer to have one viewmodel for the relevant ( that may a module or section like restaurant)